# OpenCV circle detection C# implementation

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, hough-transform

I need help from any C# and or OpenCV experts in making my circle detection script more accurate.

In OpenCV circle detection is accomplished by something called HoughCircles algorithm or framework.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

I am using a C# wrapper of OpenCV (for Unity)
[OpenCVforUnity HughCircles](http://enoxsoftware.github.io/OpenCVForUnity/doc/html/class_open_c_v_for_unity_1_1_imgproc.html#aa30b5390a304c18e3e2fdd7aa5a740d3) 
which in turn is directly based on the official java wrapper of OpenCV.

My circle detection code is as follows (without the OpenCv dependencies of course)
I've also attached 2 images so you can see the results.
What changes are needed to improve the results? I've also included the original 2 images for reference.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using OpenCVForUnity;


public class HoughCircleSample : MonoBehaviour{
    Point pt;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
            {
                        Texture2D imgTexture = Resources.Load ("balls2_bw") as Texture2D;

                        Mat imgMat = new Mat (imgTexture.height, imgTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC3);

                        Utils.texture2DToMat (imgTexture, imgMat);
                        //Debug.Log ("imgMat dst ToString " + imgMat.ToString ());

                        Mat grayMat = new Mat ();
                        Imgproc.cvtColor (imgMat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

                        Imgproc.Canny (grayMat, grayMat, 50, 200);

                         Mat circles = new Mat();    
     int minRadius = 0;
       int maxRadius = 0;

        // Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles

        Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayMat, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 3, grayMat.rows() / 8, 200, 100, minRadius, maxRadius);

       Debug.Log ("circles toString " + circles.ToString ());
        Debug.Log ("circles dump" + circles.dump ());

        if (circles.cols() > 0)
        for (int x = 0; x < Math.Min(circles.cols(), 10); x++)

        {
                double[] vCircle = circles.get(0, x);

                if (vCircle == null)
                    break;

                pt = new Point(Math.Round(vCircle[0]), Math.Round(vCircle[1]));
                int radius = (int)Math.Round(vCircle[2]);
                // draw the found circle  
                Core.circle(imgMat, pt, radius, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);

            }


 Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (imgMat.cols (), imgMat.rows (), TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
                        Utils.matToTexture2D (imgMat, texture);

                        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = texture;

                }

        }
```

[image: circle detection sample 1]

[image: circle detection sample 2]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's ok a solution in C++, upload the original image so I can try it. But then then it's up to you to convert to C#

Comment: take a look if that's what you expected..

Comment: thanks, but changing JUST the accumulator threshold yielded almost identical results. I'm getting closer  though, please see below.

Comment: have you removed also Canny step?

Answer (score 2):

This code is in C++, but you can easily convert to C#.

I needed to change the `param2` of `HoughCircle` to 200, resulting in:

```
HoughCircles(grayMat, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 3, grayMat.rows / 8, 200, 200, 0, 0);
```

which is

> the accumulator threshold for the circle centers at the detection stage. The smaller it is, the more false circles may be detected. Circles, corresponding to the larger accumulator values, will be returned first.

You also should't feed `HoughCircles` with a "Canny-ed" image, since will already take care of this. Use the `grayMat` without Canny edge detection step applied.

Results are shown below. The second one is more tricky, because of the light conditions.

[image]

[image]

Here is the whole code. Again, it's C++, but may be useful as a reference.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(){

    Mat3b src = imread("path_to_image");
    Mat1b src_gray;
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 3, src_gray.rows / 8, 200, 200, 0, 0);

    /// Draw the circles detected
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // circle center
        circle(src, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
        // circle outline
        circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
    }

    imshow("src", src);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your results are obviously correct, could you post your entire code?

Comment: @eco_bach I just tried adding Canny on the image... results are much worse. Don't use it!

Comment: Sorry Miki. How complicated is it if I have to rewrite the c++ version to c#? Which classes do I have to rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

In the fourth parameter you have set a 3, but most of your images have a ratio close to 1, this could be a probable improvement, also you have to try another set of values in the parameters 6 and 7, because this values depend on the contours extracted by a [canny edge detector](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html), I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting much closer now with 2 overlapping circles for each ball object. If I can correct for this it is basically solved.

```
Imgproc.Canny (grayMat, grayMat, 500, 200);

Mat circles = new Mat();
int minRadius =50;
int maxRadius = 200;

Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayMat, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, grayMat.rows() / 4, 1000, 1, minRadius, maxRadius);![solution3][1]
```